# Force Full-Screen mode - Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1

I am working on an app for Windows 8.1. I want to force the user to use full-screen.

I have tried adding a class with an Event Handler, but I have too many pages to add it to, so I was looking for a shortcut. Tried to inherit the pages from the class like:

```
public class ScreenManager : Page { ... }
```

and

```
public class MyPage : ScreenManager { ... }
```

This is ok, but I can't use *Frame.Navigate()*

So, is there a fix for this method? Or is it another way to deny the user split-screen mode?

Comment: Edit the question and add a tag to indicate the programming language you use.

Comment: Post the code of your base classes, so that we can see what you did. Where can't you use `Frame.Navigate()` and where could you use it before?